# Gradle jlink options gives access rights warning

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, java-module, jlink

Using Gradle, this is a very common script for jlink:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id "org.beryx.jlink" version "2.16.3"
}

jlink {
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'helloFX'
    }
}
```

For a reason unknown to me, IntelliJ always gives me this warning for `options`:

> Access to 'options' exceeds its access rights. Cannot assign a value
>   to final field 'options'.

And a warning for `['--strip-debug', '--compress', ... ]`:

> Cannot apply default constructor for class 'ListProperty'.

I don't know what is causing it.  This is pretty much a copy-paste from [gluon's javafx help](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/IDE/IntelliJ/Modular/Gradle/hellofx/build.gradle), though my project is multimodule.  I don't see why that would change anything.  Everything else in gluon's script works fine.  jlink even creates a launcher with the name 'helloFX' which works.  I don't know how I might check to see if any of the options are working.  I would imagine they are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be warning that `jlink.options` is final, and the `options == []` format is actually an implicit constructor. This is a problem because the options are already created when the jlink extension is created.

Or, it *seems* that way, but [it is probably a bug in IDEA's Gradle support for custom plugins](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-212386).

But, since it is already created, can we use the setter as a workaround?

```
options.set([ '--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages' ])
```

This seems to work to remove the warning in the IDE. There is also an `addOptions` method exposed, so we could probably do this as well:

```
addOptions('--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages')
```

This latter convenience seems to be the same as `options.addAll()` but with some sanity checks. To me, it seems more Groovy.